# CATextLayer in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

I would like to use a `CATextLayer` to display some partially bolded text in the form of a `NSAttributedString` - but would still like to use the convenience of IB for positioning.

Is there a way to drop in a `CATextLayer` with interface builder? Or what is the next best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure a `UIView` subclass in IB then set its `layerClass` to `CATextLayer` in code:

```
+ (Class)layerClass;
{
    return [CATextLayer class];
}
```

In the view's `init` method(s) configure your `CATextLayer` properties.

To access the layer's properties:

```
CATextLayer *textLayer = (CATextLayer *)self.layer;
textLayer.string = @"Foo";
// etc...
```

Comment: So I have attempted this method but as my new subclass inherits from UIView it doesn't know about the CATextLayer methods. `self.myView.string = @"test";` gives `Property 'string' not found on object of type 'MyView *'`

Comment: The property is on the layer, not the view.  See additional code sample in answer edit.

Comment: Ahh yes, ok that is working now. Although thinking about it I could just create my CATextLayer in code then add it as a sublayer to my positioning UIView. Save the trouble of subclassing UIView